# Spring Integration WS Response Message Logging

Tags: spring-integration

Please let me know if there is any way to intercept the soap response sent to ws inbound gateway, add meta information to SOAP header and pass the entire soap envelope to SI file outbound adapter, which will log the response in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement `EndpointInterceptor` and inject it into `AbstractEndpointMapping`.

In its `handleResponse()` you can get access to the

```
SoapMessage soapMessage = ((SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse());
```

do anything you want and send a Spring Integration Message to the injected channel for that `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

**UPDATE**

> 1) The response sent back to ws inbound gateway is also modified, which i do not want. I want only the soap response sent to file adapter to be modified. Because that has some meta information to be logged 2) How to make the file file outbound adapter logging asynchronous.. like wiretap.

Sorry for delay, first of all.

No, you can't do that with the same object. It's typical issue with the mutable object in the multi-threaded environment. If one thread modify object, another can see those changes. In this case the `WireTap` won't help.

I suggest you to `clone` your SOAP Message object somehow, or even better convert it to String, build a new message and only after that send it to the file adapter:

```
TransformerHelper transformerHelper = new TransformerHelper();
Result result = new StringResult();
SoapMessage soapMessage = ((SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse());
Source source = soapMessage.getEnvelope().getSource();
transformerHelper.transform(source, result);
String responseXml = result.toString();
```

Comment: Hi Artem, I have a messageContext object available through out the message processing(Using end point interceptor .handleRequest(), I saved it in thread local). So my idea was in the response channel interceptor, i will call messageContext.getResponse() to get the response soap envelope. But it is coming as empty. So I am not sure where in the actual message processing cycle, message context is updated with response message. ( I used this concept to log the request message using messageContext.getRequest())

Comment: I think the issue that your `ThreadLocal` variable isn't updated at all, because it becomes irrelevant for the actually response process. You really should do response stuff in the `handleResponse()`  of your interceptor. Right, I remember all your other questions on the matter and it is really strange for me that you don't come back to them with updates...

Comment: :) Hi Artem. I got it working. But two issues. 1) The response sent back to ws inbound gateway is also modified, which i do not want. I want only the soap response  sent to file adapter to be modified. Because that has some meta information to be logged 2) How to make the file file outbound adapter logging asynchronous.. like wiretap.

Comment: Please, take a look into my `UPDATE`.

Comment: yes that is the only solution. I tried it and is working